# arguments for partial function in python

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a function defined like this:

```
def func(self, boolVal):
```

and I want to create a connection between `QPushButton()` and this function like this:

```
self.button1.clicked.connect(partial(self.func, False))
```

when I run this, it tells me that `func()` takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
anyone knows why this could happened?

Comment: Probably the button passes some `event` parameter to the function. You could check by allowing for a third parameter and printing it.

Comment: is there any way to check this ?

Comment: What happen if you replace the line with `self.button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.func(False))`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`functools.partial` works fine.

See following example:

```
from functools import partial
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__()
        self.button = QPushButton('test', parent=self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(partial(self.func, False))
        self.button.show()
    def func(self, boolVar):
        print boolVar

app = QApplication([])
win = MyWindow()
win.show()
app.exec_()
```

If you still get error replace `func` signature with:

```
def func(self, boolVar, checked):
    print boolVar
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument is the `self` parameter, which is bound when you write `self.func`.  The second argument is the `False` you supplied to `partial`, so when Qt calls it with a third bool `checked` parameter from `QPushButton.clicked` you end up with 3 arguments.

Just write:

```
self.button1.clicked.connect(self.func)
```

However, the `checked` parameter is optional so `func` should be defined as:

```
def func(self, checked=False):
```

Comment: but I need to pass a value to func (true or false)